# Split dataframe by year

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data and code below how can I split the below `df` by year and name the subsequent `dfs` `MR_2022` and so on?

```
Code:

# Sample data
df = structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 35555, 35555, 35555
), year = c(2022, 2022, 2021, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2018, 
2022, 2022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

# Split df by year
df %>% subset() #?....
```

Comment: You need `split(df, df$year)`

Comment: Thank you, this will take care of the new `dfs` naming convention too?

Comment: You can change the name as `lst1 <- split(df, df$year); names(lst1) <- paste0("MR_", names(lst1)); list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)` if you want objects in global env